# reorder cells in UItableView and insert (new order) into database

Tags: ios, uitableview, sdk, insert

I have a table populated by an NSMutableArray.  The user has the ability to reorder the cells (rows) how they want.  I want to insert the records into the database from the array inheriting the reordered sequence.

So say the table loaded:
row 1
row 2
row 3
row 4

And the user reorders to:
row 4
row 2
row 1
row 3

I want to push the data to the database with the reordered sequence.  However when I insert all four rows via looping after reordering the rows via UITableView, the order goes into the database with the original order (not the rearranged order).

Is there a way to refresh the array from the reordered table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better way is to store the row number as a field along with other cell data. This way whenever you want to show the data again you have the row number to construct user's order.

Comment: I am not sure I follow.  I pull from the database into an array, then from the array the records are pulled into a table. I sort the table and the array knows not of that reorder (layer independence).  I push now from the array back to the database (order retains the sort from the original pull). So the question is, how can the sort update the array sort prior to the array being pushed to the database. I have not been able to figure out how to capture a reorder event vis-a-vis an array getting updated.

Comment: Add one more attribute to your entity called order. This field will hold the index of that cell in the table view. So when the users changes the order, this field gets updated and cells in table are ordered according to this field.

Answer (score 2):

Your records should have an 'order' field and store it to database. When loading from database you should sort the records with the field.

EDIT: the code below illustrates the idea

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {
    if (destinationIndexPath.row > sourceIndexPath.row) {
        for (NSInteger row = sourceIndexPath.row + 1; row <= destinationIndexPath.row; ++row) {
            Record* record = array[row];
            record.row = [NSNumber numberWithInt:record.row.intValue - 1];
        }
    } else if (destinationIndexPath.row < sourceIndexPath.row) {
        for (NSInteger row = destinationIndexPath.row; row < sourceIndexPath.row; ++row) {
            Record* record = array[row];
            record.row = [NSNumber numberWithInt:record.row.intValue + 1];
        }
    }
    Record* record = array[sourceIndexPath.row];
    record.row = [NSNumber numberWithInt:destinationIndexPath.row];
    [array removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [array insertObject:record atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
    [self save];
}

- (void)loadFromCoreData {
    NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Record" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    request.entity = entity;

    NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"row" ascending:YES];
    NSArray* sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;

    NSError* error;
    array = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
}
```

Comment: can I push records from a UITable view into an array?  Coz if so I could truncate the array and refresh it using the table records and then push it back to the database.

Comment: Well, `UITableView` is just a view for your model(array). I will update my answer with some code.

Comment: Actually my last edit was the update. Let me know if you need more info.